# Wrong path with images on Hugo page

Tags: markdown, hugo

I'm trying to make a page on hugo with images, using markdown, but when i work on local i use

```
![Image1](images/Image1.png)
```

and the path on the web is something like https://myweb/path/page-name/images/Image1.png

so the path in the web didn't work, i need to change the path to:

```
![Image1](../images/Image1.png)
```

In summary, I can not see the images on the web and local at the same time, could something be done to see them on both sites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have project structure like this, where one image is in a page bundle, and the other image is in the `static` dir.

```
├── content
│   └── path
│       └── page-name
│           ├── images
│           │   └── Image1.png
│           └── index.md
├── static
│   └── images
│       └── Image1.png
```

Then in `content/path/page-name/index.md`, here is how you would refer to each image, by absolute path.

```
<!-- page bundle image -->
![Image1](/path/page-name/images/Image1.png)

<!-- static image -->
![Image1](/images/Image1.png)
```

Keep in mind that the page bundle image path will depend on how your permalinks are configured.